# Modify default behaviour of TetGen

Tags: c++, tetgen

I am writing some code that utilizes the [TetGen library](http://wias-berlin.de/software/tetgen/) to find the convex hull of a set of points. However, by default

```
tetrahedralize("Q", &in, &temp);
```

generates both the convex hull *and* the 3D Delaunay tetrahedralization. I am inclined to believe that it is possible to get only the convex hull as Mathematica has a working implementation of Tetgen and a corresponding function `TetGenConvexHull[]` that does so, but after going through the `tetgen.cxx` source code and [documentation](http://wias-berlin.de/software/tetgen/1.5/doc/manual/manual005.html), I can't seem to find out how.

How can I modify the default behaviour of TetGen to only get the convex hull?

Answer (score 2):

In short, you can not. TetGen (version 1.4.3) computes the delaunay tetrahedralization and from that the hull is extracted. What you can do is use the `"E"` option to not generate the `*.ele`. If you only need a convex hull, you may want to look at [qhull](http://www.qhull.org/) and there the `qconvex` fucntion.